# Cloth collision with rigid body stuck at starting point

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I wanted to simulate an object falling above a cloth, but found that it kept falling through no matter what I do, while trying to figure out what's wrong I also found that when I put the object under the cloth, it seems that the collision stays where the object was and didn't really "follow" it. Sorry if I'm not communicating things clearly, I'm new to blender.

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: did you set the collision physics on apple?

Answer (score 0):

At the physics tab add a cloth physics and scroll down a bit, you should see the Collisions title. Open it up by clicking on it then enable the self collisions.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, the cloth is acting as if the apple is still there. The apple is using rigid body and collision, but even though the apple has moved because of the rigid body physics, the cloth still thinks it's where it was at the starting point. If I move the apple above the cloth, it will ignore the apple completely and the apple will fall through it instead.

Comment: try applying all transform to the apple.
you can do this by ctrl+A > all transform.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic issue.

As seen in this video at 15:00 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HRIG04a4X0?t=900

You need to:

1. click on the rigid body object (the one which initial position seems to stay where it is and blocks the cloth),
2. Go to its Rigid Body properties (in the physics tab),
3. Under Collisions, **change the Source from "Deform" to "Base".**

Another pre-requisite is that **Collisions** are enabled, additionnally to the Cloth simulation or the Rigid Body simulation (but I can't remember if it has to be on the Cloth or Rigid Body or both)